# How can I implement a check box in django

Tags: django

I have a PC based gui app and I am trying to duplicate the same functionality in a browser based solution using django. On the PC I have a check box that enables extra functionality for the user. All that I need to do is return the value (True or False) when the box is checked and this will alter the logic in the views module.

I have implemented the check box as:

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="use_stages" value="use_stages">Use stages
</form>
```

The check box appears in the browser but it will not allow me to check it.

I have looked at django forms but that seems like overkill for such a  simple requirement. Will I have to go down that route?

I am not wedded to a check box. Maybe a button would do with the text toggling as the user clicks on it.

Can anyone suggest how I should proceed from here?

Here is the code for the template:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    """Home page."""
    context = {}
    url = 'boards/home.html'
    return render(request, url, context)
```

**Solution**

To amplify sandeep's answer below, This is now the code in my template:

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="use_stages" {% if use_stages %} checked="checked"{% endif %} value= "1">Use stages
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and this is in views:

```
def my_url(request):
    context = <get context dict from somewhere>
    if request.method == 'POST':
        use_stages = request.POST.get('use_stages', 0)
        context['use_stages'] = use_stages == '1'
    url = 'boards/main_screen.html'
return render(request, url, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

in template:

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="use_stages" value="1">Use stages
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        check = request.POST.get('use_stages', 0)
        print(check) # 1 (True) or 0 (False)

    context = {

    }
    url = 'boards/home.html'
    return render(request, url, context)
```

if checkbox is check, value of check will be 1 otherwise 0. You can use this as True (1) or False (0)

Comment: Thanks. Two problems:  where does the code go in views (don't I need a method?); and the check box doesn't change when I click on it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Psionman, 1) can you add your view for this template. I will add code in view. 2) "check box doesn't change when I click on it" I don't get it. is this in template?

Comment: 1) I have added code in question. 2) works OK inFirefox, but not in Epiphany!

Comment: Do you have any other fields in form or only this check box?

Comment: Only the checkbox. I want to 'read' the value when I refresh the page

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The request method is always GET and nothing gets picked up when I click the checkbox

Comment: did you mention method = 'post'? <form method='post'>. you have to submit the form. I have edited the answer

Comment: @Psionman I have added submit button. You have to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've amplified on your answer in my question to show how I've implemented it in my case

Answer (score 0):

In Models.py file , you can add a attribute with BooleanField 
ex : featured    = models.**BooleanField(default=False)** 
this will show a checkbox with default value as unchecked